# How can I make an alert appear after calling DriveApp in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, alert

I'm trying to show an alert using Apps Script, but I can't make an alert show up after I've called DriveApp. This code demonstrates the problem. What do I need to do to make the second alert appear?

```js
function onOpen(e) {
  // apps script function called on opening of google spreadsheet
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  ui.alert("Before DriveApp"); // this alert appears
  var spreadsheetFile = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId);
  ui.alert("After DriveApp"); // this alert does not appear
}
```

Comment: the problem is not the alert .. the problem is that the line before the alert surely threw an exception... what did you see in the js console? And anyway just for the sake of records, you need to close the alert dialog user-side to let the next statement execute, because it halts code execution

Comment: Thanks for your advice @Diego De Vita. The problem was that i was using a simple onOpen instead of an installable onOpen. I found the information in the post "My onOpen trigger is running only half of the script" addressed the issue I was encountering.